# Error on my Network Admin Dashboard in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

So my Network Admin Dashboard on my Wordpress site is giving me this error at the top:

> **Notice:** is_current_page was called incorrectly. Function was called before it is possible to accurately determine what the current
>   page is. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This
>   message was added in version 4.5.6.) in
>   /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4139

It repeats this quite a few times. How do I get it to go away? It happened after I deleted a plugin that was causing an issue with another plugin.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

This is on line 4139:

```
 * Filters whether to trigger an error for _doing_it_wrong() calls.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 *
 * @param bool $trigger Whether to trigger the error for _doing_it_wrong() calls. Default true.
 */
if ( WP_DEBUG && apply_filters( 'doing_it_wrong_trigger_error', true ) ) {
    if ( function_exists( '__' ) ) {
        if ( is_null( $version ) ) {
            $version = '';
        } else {
            /* translators: %s: version number */
            $version = sprintf( __( '(This message was added in version %s.)' ), $version );
        }
        /* translators: %s: Codex URL */
        $message .= ' ' . sprintf( __( 'Please see <a href="%s">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.' ),
            __( 'https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress' )
        );
        /* translators: Developer debugging message. 1: PHP function name, 2: Explanatory message, 3: Version information message */
        trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );
    } else {
        if ( is_null( $version ) ) {
            $version = '';
        } else {
            $version = sprintf( '(This message was added in version %s.)', $version );
        }
        $message .= sprintf( ' Please see <a href="%s">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information.',
            'https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress'
        );
        trigger_error( sprintf( '%1$s was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. %2$s %3$s', $function, $message, $version ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's on line 4139 of your functions.php file? Have you tried deactivating all your plugins?

Comment: No i haven't tried deactivating all the plugins yet. I'll give that a try

Comment: Ok I network deactivated all the plugins and it still shows up...

Answer (score 0):

I made the error go away by adding an @ before line 4139.

@trigger_error( sprintf( __( '%1$s was called **incorrectly**. %2$s %3$s' ), $function, $message, $version ) );